# adding MeshOutline to an object on the HoloLens gives me a jagged outline

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to apply an outline shader to a 3d model on the HoloLens.
Fortunately, I found a MeshOutline.cs script on the MRTK example and have been doing some testing with this component.
The outline looks very good when the app runs inside the Unity editor on PC. However, when I build the app on the HoloLens I get a very jagged outline which is very similar to the screenshot in the following link: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5063#issuecomment-519860449

I have tried adding MeshSmoother component to the model, which has not been helpful.
Any suggestions on how to achieve a clean outline effect?

Comment: never mind. I've found the solution!

Comment: If possible, please feel free to share your finding. Thanks!